# htaccess redirects in wordpress iste

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm moving a site from static html to the wordpress platform and trying to set up redirects but I can't seem to get it working.  The site is at http://slysmidtown.com

What I would like to do is redirect requests for menu.html  to /menu/

and redirect all other .html file requests to index.php or just http://slysmidtown.com

this is what I have so far the top line almost works so that the site will load but still requests the html file the rest is written by wordpress

```
RewriteEngine on
rewriterule ^menu.html(.*)$ http://slysmidtown.com/menu/$1 [r=301,nc]


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot that you need to rewrite it back internally to a file, since Apache doesn't know how to handle /menu/ urls now. To prevent infinite redirects you need to let the redirect only match on an external request:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /menu\.html\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /menu/ [R,L]

RewriteRule ^menu/?$ /menu.html [L]
```

Comment: That works Thanks a lot for the quick answer.  Could I add this somehow  to redirect any other html requests to the index or home page I thought it might work if I put it after but it doesn't seem to      RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^.*\.html$ /index.php [R=301,L]

Comment: Make sure to change `[R,L]` to `[R=301,L]` after testing all works properly.

Answer (score -1):

You had the rule in the wrong place, placing it just after the rewritebase should work/:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Rewriterule ^menu.html(.*)$ http://slysmidtown.com/menu/$1 [r=301,nc]
Rewriterule ^(.*).html(.*)$ http://slysmidtown.com/ [r=301,nc]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```